# asrock h61m-hvs motherboard pin connections

Tags: motherboard

While trouble shooting my on/off switch, I accidentally unplugged 8 small wires 3 double connectors and 2 single.  I could sure use a pic of how they go back as I have no idea and afraid of smoking something.  This is an Ibuypower computer 3-4 years old.  They go to a white 9 pin socket near the USB sockets.  I believe it was #13 in the online manual.  System battery is right above it. Any help would be very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're talking about your panel header. It looks something like this, right?

[image: Gigabyte version]

They look a little different across motherboard manufacturers, but I'm pretty sure this is what we're discussing.  [I'm looking at the manual](https://www.slideshare.net/iimazizah1/h61-m-vg3p) and this is item 12.

You're right that this can cook a thing if you do it wrong, but it's pretty easy to do right.   Especially if the motherboard has markings to indicate which side is positive and negative and which plug to use on the board, and ASUS boards usually do.  As long as you match up the labels on the plastic connector for each wire or wire pair with where it goes on the board, and follow the positive/negative indicators, you'll be fine.

This is my single least favorite part of putting a computer together, because the design of this header is horrible for human hands.   ASUS boards usually come with a small plastic brick passthrough just so you can plug the wires into that and that onto the header itself.  If you've got one, or that's what is left on the board, carefully remove it from the board (if it's still there), plug everything into it, then plug it back in once you have the wires on there correctly.

Comment: Took closer look after your post. Didn't realize these small wires were named. Downloaded image of my panel connector that I found on a website that had correct placement of wires. power and reset were easy, but others were a guess as all wires were black. Without your exploded pic, I would have never found it. All work but HDD LED. Wires too small and too hard to plug in , so am not opening computer again. MANY, MANY THANKS TO YOU CDAVE!!!!!

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to mark your answer so we know it's solved!

Comment: Question is answered.  How do I mark it so?